# Print layout page break/ whitespace issue ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Having a report with 5 different tables and what i want is to have each of these tables starting at the top of a new page. These tables are currently in a rectangle each which has a hide/show expression. Surrounding these rectangles is a list which is doing the correct grouping for the tables and also doing page breaks after each group(3 groups in total: Association, Organization, and Type. There are 5 different types, one for each table(there's a filter on the tables).

When showing my report in regular preview mode there is no problem but when doing so in print layout preview I get the third table starting on the third page but not at the top and after that I dont know what is happening... all page breaks just stops working. Sometimes whole empty pages are rendered.

[This is how the report layout looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGmu9.png)

[This is some of the resulting pages (not in order)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPlHS.png)

Just so you know, I have been trying consumewhiteSpace, Checking the height and width on my report Height = 15,1cm and width 24cm and its just a horisontal A4 page.

The grey color is the list-rectangle. Why is it acting up like that and how do I make it work?

Comment: How about instead of a rectangle, putting the tables in separate lines in a table and then hiding the row?

Comment: @HannoverFist Hi, tried it now, but the tables still seems to jump around quite a bit, unfortunately. The hiding bit seems to work though still. Looked through other reports i have done which worked, but when adding just a teeny tiny bit of more space on them resulted in the same current problem... I dont get it :/

Comment: Have you considered using subreports instead of multiple tables like this? Also, these 5 tables seem to be in a group of its own. Are these 5 tables inside one big giant cell of one big giant table?

Comment: I'll try subreports in a minute. Yes the list/table have 3 groups on which I have page break and sorting on. I'm feeling so blind, needing to see outside of the box... Didnt think about testing table nor subreports until you guys said it :S :) @CrazyCucumber

Comment: @CrazyCucumber Hi, with the subreports all the page breaks stoped working, it doesent seem to follow the main report grouping(the tables render strangely and in a new order) and it is very performance demanding. 
The tables  where first in a list-rectangle so you could say one and the same cell. When trying HannoverFist example they ended up in a row each of a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the report is fixed. Don't really know what I did but I redid the report(like a houndred times before), really made sure that all the page breaks, filters, report margins and visibility conditions (not only in the tables visibility propery but also on every static row under advanced mode) were right. I made some table changes for example using stepped table instead of nested. And found some wrongs I had made previous considering the tables layout (guess everything has a purpos even hard work and long wait...).

Thanks for the help though!